# Multiple Inputs in one scanf showing a miscellanous behaviour

Tags: c, scanf

I was trying a simple calculation using long data types. Addition of three numbers. But while I take inputs in one scanf function, it take takes intial two input as zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
long x,y,z;
printf("Input x,y,x:\n");
scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&x,&y,&z);
printf("Result: %lld\n",x+y+z);
return 0;
}
```

The code works perfectly fine in online compiler but not in my vscode. I checked the version of C we are using the same.
I changed the code a little, i.e.,

```
scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&z,&y,&x);
```

and now it works perfectly fine.
Why? How can just the arrangement of variable solved the issue.
I did the initial code in int data type with %d format specifier, it worked perfectly fine but not the same with long and %lld.
Can anyone explain why this happened or what is the error.
Why does it works on online compiler but not my vs code.

I was expecting the sum of three numbers.

Comment: The correct specifier for a ```long``` is ```%ld```, not ```%lld```. Other than that, your code works compiles and works just fine for me, with warnings enabled.

Comment: Maybe you're building a 32-bit program and the online compiler is building a 64-bit program.  On Unix-like systems, with a 64-bit system, `long` and `long long` are the same size, so your code works, mostly by accident.  On a 32-bit system, `long` and `long long` are different sizes so you get different behaviour.  Strictly, it is undefined in both versions.  Windows throws another spanner in the works; it is configured so that `long` is a 32-bit type, even in Windows 64.  In that respect, it behaves a bit like a 32-bit system (but pointers are like a 64-bit system).

Comment: Newbie, save time.  Enable all compilers warnings.

Comment: Newbie, why  does code use `"%lld"` with `long`?

Answer (score 1):

The `%lld` specifier expect the address of a `long long`.  You instead passed in the address of a `long`.  Using the wrong format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What most likely happened, given that you're using VS Code and therefore most likely running on Windows, on that system a `long` is 4 bytes while a `long long` is 8 bytes.  So when `scanf` attempts to read a value, it writes 8 bytes into the the pointer it's given instead of 4, writing past the end of a variable and most likely into another.

The online compiler you're using is probably using gcc which has an 8 byte `long` so it happens to work.

You should instead be using the `%ld` format specifier which expects the address of a `long`.

```
scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&x,&y,&z);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you have used the wrong format specifier of `long`. Either declare the variables as `long` and use the format specifier as `%ld` or declare the variables as `long long` and use the format specifier as `%lld`